# Props conditional rendering using styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am using styled-components library inside a React application and I have this block for example:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background: red;
`;
```

I need to add some other style if a prop has a set value, something like:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background: red;
  color: white; // color should be added only if this.props.myProps == 'ok'
`;
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another syntax option.
<sub>*This is actually how I write all my styled-components now. It makes things easier to iterate/update.*</sub>

```js
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const Wrapper = styled.div(
  (props) => css`
    background: red;

    ${props.isOK &&
    css`
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    `}
  `
);
```

Comment: import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

Answer (score 4):

For one style:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    background: red;
    color: ${props => props.myProps === 'ok' && 'white'};
`;
```

For multiple styles:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    background: red;
    ${props => {
        if (props.myProps === 'ok') return `
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        `
    }}
`;
```

Another option is to use `styled.css`:

```
// Define a pure group of css properties
const okStyle = styled.css`
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
`;

// Reuse okStyle inside a styled component
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    background: red;
    ${props => props.myProps === 'ok' && okStyle}
`;
```

Comment: what if my prop is != 'ok'? will `color` be added in the CSS? is there a different way? i need to add more than just `color`

Comment: `color` will be null, so no change

Comment: I updated my answer with the code for multiple styles

Comment: which one of my solutions did you try? 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: Also check your version of `styled-components` in your `package.json` file.  The current version is `5.1.0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213239/discussion-between-aletede91-and-hermitcrab).

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background: red;
  color: ${p => p.isOk ? 'white' : 'green'}; // color will be added only if this.props.myProps == 'ok', else color will be green
`;
```

To send this props you should use syntax like

```
return (
  <Wrapper isOk={true}>Some text</Wrapper>
)
```